# Flutter build windows fails because of a cmake permissions error

Tags: c++, flutter, windows, dart, cmake

Im encountering an issue with the windows build of my flutter app maid (Available here https://github.com/danemadsen/maid). The build fails because of a CMake error stating "file cannot create directory: C:/maid/build/windows/x64/$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:maid>/lib.  Maybe need administrative privileges". This error is only present when trying to build for windows, all other platforms build fine. Here is the full error readout

```
[   +5 ms]   CMake Error at llama/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
[        ]     file cannot create directory:
[        ]     C:/maid/build/windows/x64/$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:maid>/lib.  Maybe need
[        ]     administrative privileges.
[        ]   Call Stack (most recent call first):
[        ]     cmake_install.cmake:310 (include)
[   +5 ms] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] Done Building Project "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
[        ] Build FAILED.
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\common\common.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj" (default target) (6) ->
[        ] (ClCompile target) ->
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(1055,31): warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float' [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(1205,40): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u0120' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(1206,40): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u010A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(1207,40): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u0120' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(1208,40): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u010A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(2244,60): warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u010A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252) [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(9753,28): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\llama.cpp(9783,28): warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\llama.vcxproj]
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\common\common.vcxproj" (default target) (5) ->
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\common\console.cpp(253,30): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\common\common.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\common\console.cpp(407,28): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\common\common.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\common\common.cpp(785): warning C4715: 'gpt_random_prompt': not all control paths return a value [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\llama\common\common.vcxproj]
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\butler\butler.vcxproj" (default target) (8) ->
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\common\log.h(379,19): warning C4996: 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\butler\butler.vcxproj]
[        ]   C:\maid\src\llama.cpp\common\log.h(387,97): warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details. [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\butler\butler.vcxproj]
[        ] "C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
[        ] (PostBuildEvent target) ->
[        ]   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Release -P cmake_install.cmake [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ] C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(161,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [C:\maid\build\windows\x64\INSTALL.vcxproj]
[        ]     13 Warning(s)
[        ]     1 Error(s)
[        ] Time Elapsed 00:00:16.92
[  +16 ms] Building Windows application... (completed in 19.3s)
[        ] "flutter windows" took 19,857ms.
[   +2 ms] Build process failed.
[        ]
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _runBuild (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:253:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      buildWindows (package:flutter_tools/src/windows/build_windows.dart:106:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildWindowsCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_windows.dart:56:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1350:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:348:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:294:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:112:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[ +267 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 263ms
[        ] Running 0 shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
PS C:\maid> flutter update
Could not find a command named "update".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
PS C:\maid> flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel beta
Flutter 3.16.0-0.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fe6553b689 (6 days ago) • 2023-10-11 19:07:11 -0700
Engine • revision 249cc9b86c
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 (build 3.2.0-210.2.beta) • DevTools 2.28.1
```

I tried:

- running flutter clean before i rebuild.
- running flutter build windows in administrator powershell.
- recreating the windows platform files with flutter create .
- a different windows machine.
- windows 10 and windows 11.
- reinstalling flutter.
- reinstalling cmake.
- the latest CMake version available in android studio (3.22.1)
- using the latest Cmake version available externally to android studio (3.28.0)
- switching to the beta channel of flutter.